# tracking all child process spawned by a root process

Tags: python, linux, process

I'm inspecting a certain make system that runs compilers. I want to track all child processes ever spawned by such a "root" process.

I'm aware there's the `ps` command and as I'm a Python user, the `psutil` package. But I'm not sure if I'll miss some short lived processes between the calls.

I think what I really want is something like `inotify` (or `watchdog` in Python), but instead of tracking directory, it tracks all child process activity.

Is there such a system call, or preferably, package of Python, that does this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't know about python in particular but `strace -f -e trace=process <executable>` will give you that info. Albeit in a format that will require some (not too difficult) parsing.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks I knew there must be something for this purpose :) Would you please write an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sttace` can provide that info. But you may have to parse the output to get just the info you are interested in.

```
strace -f -e trace=process <executable>
```

That will trace all child processes of `<executable>` and will trace only the process related syscalls (essentially `wait`, `fork`, `clone` and `exec`).