# Get new pid from nd_syscall.vfork.return in systemtap

Tags: linux-kernel, systemtap, vfork

I'm trying to [extract things from a weird makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011209/tracking-all-child-process-spawned-by-a-root-process), and I found that systemtap is a potential good solution so here I am:

I can get correct `pid()` `ppid()` called from the new process when probing with `nd_syscall.clone.return`, however this doesn't include all the vforks I've found in my target script.

So when I use the probe `nd_syscall.vfork.return`, I've found that the message has clone caller's `pid()` and `ppid()` only, I've tried to get the return value of vfork but it doesn't seem to be the new pid (that I've seen from many related execve events).

I cannot use `kprocess` since I don't want to install debug info.

What's some way to get the correct new_pid from vfork? Did I miss some args? Or did I use the wrong probe function? There has to be a way, thanks!

P.S. I've tried sysdig but it skips a lot of events BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried kernel tracepoint probes?

```
probe kernel.trace("sched_process_fork") {
   printf("%d->%d\n", $parent->pid, $child->pid)
}
```